# Why is java.sql.Time object giving different times one year apart?

Tags: java, date, time

I'm a bit confused as to how the java.sql.Time object calculates time.

I'm trying to setup a timer at a certain time everyday. However, when calculating the time, to place the alarm, I seem to be placing the alarm one hour ahead of what it should be.

This starts happening 494 days ago though (current date is 7/17/13). It also occurs if you go back farther (such as 1000 days ago), and I'm guessing that it cycles through +1 hour and +0 hours every couple hundred of days.

I could just subtract an hour from my input time, but I would like to understand why this is happening.

```
private static long oneDayInMill = timeToMill(24, 0); 
private static long reminderTime = timeToMill(13 + 6, 25); //military time; it starts at 18, not 0 for some reason
private static long currentTimeInMill = System.currentTimeMillis() % oneDayInMill;
private static long currentDayInMill = System.currentTimeMillis() - currentTimeInMill;

    System.out.println(new Time(currentDayInMill - (oneDayInMill*495)+ reminderTime).toString());
// This displays as 13:25:00 (as  I expect)
    System.out.println(new Time(currentDayInMill - (oneDayInMill*494)+ reminderTime).toString());
// This displays as 14:25:00 (not as I would expect)

public static long timeToMill(int hr, int min){
        //out of bounds
        return (hr*60*60*1000 + min*60*1000);
    }
```

I think the time zone used by my computer is CST (that's what outputs when I output a Date java.util.Date object)

Sorry if my question is a bit confusing

Comment: One hour difference = suspect daylight savings time/summer time.

Comment: What is you time zone?

Comment: Do you mean `java.sql.Time`?

Comment: Use SimpleTimeFormat to print out the entire time spec -- year, month, day, time zone, daylight savings, number of gerbils, everything.

Comment: @rgettman is correct.  Running this code in a loop that increments the 494/495 value by one and you will see that the two printouts vary at the daylight savings shifts.

Comment: You should use UTC timezone (`TimeZone.getTimeZone("")`) for most of your date/time calculations. Since you're in CST, that explains the 6 hour difference between your local timezone and Zulu time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rgettman and Dave Bartlett were right. If I print out the date object 495 days ago I receive

```
Sat Mar 10 18:00:00 CST 2012
```

If I print out the date object 494 days ago I receive:

```
Sun Mar 11 19:00:00 CDT 2012
```